# VS Code error 22 when running Python file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, runtime-error, execution

I am trying to run a simple python code in Visual Studio Code. My launch.json looks like this :

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python : Fichier actuel",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the full error :

```
D:\Me\Documents\MEGA\IPSA\Aéro 3\Optimisation différentiable\TP-Projet>cd "d:\Me\Documents\MEGA\IPSA\Aéro 3\Optimisation différentiable\TP-Projet" && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && "C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" """c:/Users/My Username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py""" --default --client --host localhost --port 9975 "d:\Me\Documents\MEGA\IPSA\Aéro 3\Optimisation différentiable\TP-Projet\projet.py" "
C:\Users\My Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file '"c:/Users/My Username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The debugger doesn't start and an error message telling me the debugger doesn't respond appears. Did I do anything wrong ? Is it just a bug in how VS Code handles file paths ?

Comment: looks like there's some extra quoting. Seems like a command line bug. Can you try to put your script in a folder without spaces (not your user profile) ?

Comment: Same error : `D:\TP-Projet>cd d:\TP-Projet && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && "C:\Users\My User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" """c:/Users/My User/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py""" --default --client --host localhost --port 10172 d:\TP-Projet\projet.py "
C:\Users\My User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't open file '"c:/Users/My User/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py"': [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It indeed looks like a bug, but dependant from where the Python extension is installed and not on the opened file path. Should we open a bug on Github ?

Comment: yes. `c:/Users/My User/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17517/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py` contains a space. (My User). You could try to rename your username that would be a good workaround

Comment: as a rule: don't use paths with spaces or french accents :)

Comment: that said, this is not looking good: `cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" `. The command is quoted, but there are quotes in the subcommands that should be triple quoted (or removed). Someone as Microsoft can't handle quoting properly...

Comment: This is naff. Easier to just open command window and run command.. I wanted to log output to a file!

Answer (score 1):

Also have spaces in my username and for now you only need to run, try to roll your python extension back to 2019.4.12954 to avoid.  It looks like a bug from 2019.5.17059.